# Interpreting Uniswap V3 prices

Tags: javascript, bigint, uniswap

I am quite new to JavaScript and Uniswap. I am using Uniswap V3 to fetch the price from the DAI/USDC pool. My "main" function looks as follows:

```js
async function main() {

  const [immutables, state] = await Promise.all([
    getPoolImmutables(),
    getPoolState(),
  ]);

  const DAI = new Token(1, immutables.token0, 18, "DAI", "Stablecoin");
  const USDC = new Token(1, immutables.token1, 6, "USDC", "USD Coin");

  const DAI_USDC_POOL = new Pool(
    DAI,
    USDC,
    immutables.fee,
    state.sqrtPriceX96.toString(),
    state.liquidity.toString(),
    state.tick
  );
  
  const token0Price = DAI_USDC_POOL.token0Price;

  console.log("The price is: ", token0Price);
}
```

And I am getting the following output:

```
The price is:  Price {
  numerator: JSBI(6) [
    435696740,
    805184612,
    508287463,
    671994784,
    427409972,
    4,
    sign: false
  ],
  denominator: JSBI(7) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4096, sign: false ],
  baseCurrency: Token {
    chainId: 1,
    decimals: 18,
    symbol: 'DAI',
    name: 'Stablecoin',
    isNative: false,
    isToken: true,
    address: '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F'
  },
  quoteCurrency: Token {
    chainId: 1,
    decimals: 6,
    symbol: 'USDC',
    name: 'USD Coin',
    isNative: false,
    isToken: true,
    address: '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48'
  },
  scalar: Fraction {
    numerator: JSBI(2) [ 660865024, 931322574, sign: false ],
    denominator: JSBI(1) [ 1000000, sign: false ]
  }
}
```

The USDC price seems to make some sense (denominator, 1000000), however I am not sure how to interpret the DAI price from the output. If anyone can provide any hints or point me to a resource that explains the output, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JSBI stands for [**J**ava**S**cript **B**ig**I**nt](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi):

> a [pure-JavaScript](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/blob/main/lib/jsbi.ts) implementation of the ECMAScript BigInt proposal.

It's a large integer represented through an array. To see it's decimal form, use `String(jsbi)` or `jsbi.toString()`. For calculations you have to use methods of the module:

| Mathematical Operation | JSBI Operation |
| --- | --- |
| Addition | `c = JSBI.add(a, b)` |
| Subtraction | `c = JSBI.subtract(a, b)` |
| Multiplication | `c = JSBI.multiply(a, b)` |
| Division | `c = JSBI.divide(a, b)` |

Using the values of your example we can calculate

```js
(async function asyncFnOnlyForAwait() {

const { default: JSBI } = await import ('https://cdn.skypack.dev/jsbi')

window.JSBI = JSBI;
window.priceJSBI = {
  numerator: [435696740, 805184612, 508287463, 671994784, 427409972, 4,],
  denominator: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4096, ],
  scalarNumerator: [660865024, 931322574, ],
  scalarDenominator: [1000000, ]
};
window.price = {};

// convert arrays to JSBI
for (const [prop, val] of Object.entries(priceJSBI))
  priceJSBI[prop] = JSBI.from(val)
  
// calculate using JSBI methods  
priceJSBI.value        = JSBI.divide(priceJSBI.numerator, priceJSBI.denominator)
priceJSBI.scalarValue = JSBI.divide(priceJSBI.scalarNumerator, priceJSBI.scalarDenominator)

// convert JSBIs to numbers, losing precicion
for (const [prop, val] of Object.entries(priceJSBI))
  price[prop] = JSBI.toNumber(val)

price.valueByNumbers = price.numerator / price.denominator

console.table(price)
document.write('<pre>price = '+JSON.stringify(price, null, 4))

}).call();

// In devtools console on this question, select the right iframe as scope to access these variables
// In Chromium browsers there's a dropdown for JS scopes next to the "console clear" button
```

It is odd that Uniswap ships JSBI on Desktop. It is actually meant as a fallback for older/mobile browsers and only complicates things. [BigInts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) are supported on all major browsers and use normal arithemtic operators. JSBI should actually be [transpiled away](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/babel-plugin-transform-jsbi-to-bigint) for environments with BigInts.